# Command line prompted errors

Tags: python, command-line, conditional-statements

My program takes 2 or 3 command line parameters:

-s is an optional parameter, indicating a switch in my program later on
-infile is the file input
-outfile is to be the written file

I need my program to print an error message and quit if any of the following happen:

- the user specifies an infile name that does not end with .genes
- the user specifics an outfile name that does not end with either .fa or .fasta
- the user provides less than 2, or more than 3, parameters
- the user's first parameter starts with a dash, but is not '-s'

I have written:

```
def getGenes(spliced, infile, outfile):
spliced = False
if '-s' in sys.argv:
    spliced = True
    sys.argv.remove('-s')
    infile, outfile = sys.argv[1:]
if not infile.endswith('.genes'):
    print('Incorrect input file type')
    sys.exit(1)
if not outfile.endswith('.fa' or '.fasta'):
    print('Incorrect output file type')
    sys.exit(1)
if not 2 <= len(sys.argv) <= 3:
    print('Command line parameters missing')
    sys.exit(1)
if sys.argv[1] != '-s':
    print('Invalid parameter, if spliced, must be -s')
    sys.exit(1)
```

However, something is conflicting with some of the conditionals, including the first and last one being contradictory due to the fact that s.argv[1] always unequal to '-s' becuase if 's' were present in argv, it was removed earlier. So I am not sure how to write this correctly...

Comment: Just nitpicking, but errors should be sent to stderr.

Comment: `sys.argv.remove('s')` `s` -> `-s`, no?

Comment: I would start with `argparse` module first and handle anything special afterwards.

Comment: That is not valid python code, the body of the function is not indented. It also looks like you are expecting the values of the method arguments to be passed back to the context that called this method, that will not work.

Comment: Right, I have fixed it above. Yet, since I am removing it in the first conditional. My last conditional is non-functional, correct?

Comment: Right, this python function is meant to be used later in the command line, also I think my indentation was messed up when trying to transfer it here...

Comment: How would I introduce/incorporate argparse in the conditionals above?

Comment: `outfile.endswith('.fa' or '.fasta')` is almost certainly not what you want. Try `(outfile.endswith('.fa') or outfile.endswith('.fasta'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sliced=False` is not indented

```
def getGenes(spliced, infile, outfile):
     spliced = False
```

`sys.argv.remove('s')` it should be  `sys.argv.remove('-s')`

**two conditions are contradicting each other:**

```
if '-s' in sys.argv:
    spliced = True
    sys.argv.remove('-s') # you removed '-s' from sys.argv ,so the below if condition becomes false
    infile, outfile = sys.argv[1:]  

if sys.argv[1] != '-s':
    print('Invalid parameter, if spliced, must be -s')
    sys.exit(1)
```

**Edited version of your code:**

```
import sys

def getGenes(spliced, infile, outfile):
 spliced = False
if '-s' in sys.argv:
    spliced = True
    infile, outfile = sys.argv[2:]
if not infile.endswith('.genes'):
    print('Incorrect input file type')
    sys.exit(1)
if not outfile.endswith('.fa' or '.fasta'):
    print('Incorrect output file type')
    sys.exit(1)
if not 3 <= len(sys.argv) <= 4:
    print('Command line parameters missing')
    sys.exit(1)
if sys.argv[1] != '-s':
    print('Invalid parameter, if spliced, must be -s')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why have you changed the 2 and 3 to a 3 and 4 above?

Comment: yes, because I didn't removed '-s' from sys.srgv, so it's length will be 4 now.

Comment: One more question, does the first statement work with the last statement? Because, if '-s' is not in sys.argv, then sys.argv[1] will not be equal to '-s' anyway...

Comment: Do I need to make separate ones with different len(sys.argv) for this to work the way I intended??